# GA UTM Campaign Tracking with Facebook Open Graph

Tags: facebook, google-analytics, facebook-opengraph, tracking

When I use my custom FB Open Graph action (bound to a FB article object) I submit a link to the original article on the web with Google Analytics UTM Campaign URL parameters. I assume the FB linter then crawls that article and uses the URL found in the open graph tags on the page instead of the one I submitted, which does not include any tracking data. When users click the link from my open graph post it goes to the article (external to facebook) with no original tracking information.

Any ideas on how to support url parameters or UTM campaign tracking for open graph shared links? Or is there a way to query FB insights on a domain/link level to get back click data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the optional "ref" parameter when you create OG actions. Facebook will include that value from the original ref parameter as "fb_ref" when users click your OG story links. More info is available here:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/technical-guides/opengraph/defining-an-action/

Comment: Perfect! Thank you. I'm now tracking this when I see it loading via a click thru on the page. I am curious about the whole "These values will be used to display graphs grouped by each unique value of ref in your application's insights." Haven't seen this surfaced anywhere on insights. If you have on insights or via insights api please update :-)

Comment: I haven't looked for this in Insights either... just using it for click-tracking.

Answer (score 0):

You can find it on insights, in ![enter image description here][1]demographics section

Go to 
1) App Insights
2) Select Open Graph
3) Select Demographics

on the right you search the Ref Parameter section - you should see the statistics there

Comment: you can provide more details on that

Comment: Please provide links to your answer. Answer should clearly explain the solution to problem. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer